# NSWindow black gloss title bar - ala QuickTime Player 10

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

is there a (hopefully official) way I can set my NSWindow's title bar to have the same black gloss look that QuickTime Player uses?

My window is a main app window, not an NSPanel. (It's a media playback app, for those people concerned about UI proliferation.)